# How to check if html form is edited?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

In typescript, is there a way to check if a form has changes by returning true/false. Let's say if I have first name field with current value: John. When I type Johny, it should return true. But if I revert it back to John, it means there are no changes, so it should return false.

At the moment, I am trying the below code but it's not very effective:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
  console.warn(result);
});
```

Comment: `this.form.dirty`

Answer (score 0):

Although not mentioned in your question, i assume the type of `form` is an Angular [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)

If you only need to know if there's any value you could use the `dirty` property.

```
let form = new FormControl('');
// ...
return form.dirty;
```

Or alternatively, you can use a [Validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) to restrict precisely possible values and finally check the `valid` property.

```
 let form = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(4)
 ]);
 // ...
 form.updateValueAndValidity();
 return form.valid;
```